# Slow Grails test starting in Intellij IDEA

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, intellij-idea

IDEA is starting a new Grails instance every time I wan't to run a single test.

Is there a way to use regular Grails runner but using interactive mode?
Running tests in interactive mode id blazing fast :-)

Comment: Which versions of IntelliJ and Grails?

Comment: Which kind of tests, standard Grails integration tests, functional tests (Geb?), … ?

Comment: Unit tests (with @TestFor annotation), started as 'Grails' in Intellij 11.1.3 with Grails 2.1.1

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you run it from the command line ? I have found IDE to be very slow. IF you are using version 2.1.1, you can use just the plain command grails. That will give you the interactive console and from there just run the command test-app. This will run all your test. IF you want to run any particular test, you can do that also, just take a look [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#testing) and you will see how you can run some particular test

If you are using version 1.3 you can use the command grails interactive and that will give you an interactive console. You can use the same list of command test-app to run all your tests

Comment: That sucks a bit, right? It's way easier to rerun test in IDE on which I'm currently working and not having to go to the console. I agree the command line works perfectly fine, it's just not in the same place as IDE, which means copy-pasting test names, etc